# prediction: find whether NMF feature matrix presented in new dataset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

The problem is simple: first decompose a training set using non-negative matrix factorisation (NMF), which yields `W`(so-called feature matrix) and `H`, allowing approximate `dot(W, H)==data_train`. Then, I want to find if samples in a unseen testing set (lets say `data_test`) have features presented in `W` i.e. find `H'` which assign test samples their labels/classifications/whatever the term.

I believe there should be a neat way to do this, like we can train a Gaussian mixture model and use it to predict labels. However tried the following methods/measurements on `data_train` (which means I can compare the results with ground truth `H`):

1) pseudoinverse to solve `H'` in `dot(W, H')=data_test`;

2) same equation, non-negative least squares (NNLS) to solve `H'`;

3) use `W` as a matrix encoding probability distribution, calculate expectations for samples using according entries in `W` and `data_test`, set a threshold for it;

4) spearman correlation between samples and `W`, set a threshold for it;

[and performances are kind of bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lojjH.png). `H` plotted as the blue line. They do have some consents on several peaks albeit overall performances are terrible (~`pearson(H, H')==0.3`).

Decomposition process of NMF is rather stable but seems like I just can't 'reverse' it, even when try to find `H'` using NNLS (which I think has a similar algorithm to NMF in converging part). In other words, what I'm confused with is that existing of different pairs of `W` and `H` (given by that fact `data=dot(W,inverse(Q),Q,H)` for random matrix Q) do make sense, but shouldn't I be able to converge to a place near the local minima of `H`, if `W` is fixed?

To sum up, my questions are:

1) is it even possible to find a reasonable `H'` (or to say, reproduce `H` given `W` and `data`)?

2) if it's not the case, how should I interpret `W`? In some biological papers NMF is used on find signatures (`W`) in genome data (e.g. matrix contains expression level catalogue), but if `W` can't be used to make predictions or be compared with each other, wouldn't the signatures meaningless other than some fancy patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Did some test and found out what's happening.

First of all, NMF should be able to find `W` or `H` given `V`, e.g. set update_H to `False` in python `sklearn.decomposition.non_negative_factorization`, and it is stable. The main issue is that, we do have `W inverse(Q) Q H`, however NMF itself is not robust in the way that if we feed the model with `dot(W, inverse(Q))` as `W`, seems it will not converge `H` to `dot(inverse(Q), H)` (strategy: minimize L2 norm). My data actually has been tweaked by a `Q`.

Though not sure if this is a rational explanation, as the model [would converge to some other random local minimas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WC4j.png) don't make a lot of sense to me.